# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/a8012112/public_html/application/controllers/User.php on line 18

Tags: codeigniter

This is my controller after hosting it gives error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/a8012112/public_html/application/controllers/User.php on line 18

```
 public function index()
        {
            $result = $this->Usermodel->index();
            $this->load->view('user/header');
            $this->load->view('user/index', ['result' => $result]);
            $this->load->view('user/footer');

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['result'] = $this->Usermodel->index();
        $this->load->view('user/header');
        $this->load->view('user/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer');

    }
```

And then in view you should use `$result` to get results:

```
<p>
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</p>
```

For more information and examples, check CodeIgniter documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: Nice answer bro ;)

Comment: @MindaugasM. could you explain that?

Comment: @MindaugasM. Thank you very much for providing link, but i don't feel that is clearing anything to me... Problem seems to be pure php issue. I mean - isn't `['result' => $result]` the same as `$data['result'] = $result;`?

Comment: @AnnaOleksiuk, array short tags are added to PHP 5.4 and later.